# Compiler error with ASSERT-C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int IsLocked();
};
int A::IsLocked()
{
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    A a1;
    ASSERT(a1.IsLocked());
    return 0;
}
```

getting error as assert identifier not found.... I tried including  also..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be:

```
assert(a1.IsLocked())
```

note lower case.

Comment: Additionally, the assertation will fail, as a1.IsLocked() will return false. That may be intentional, but I figured I'd mention it.